# SQL only retrieve first item in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT subject FROM book WHERE useid = $userid") or die(mysql_error());
$sub = mysql_fetch_array($search, MYSQL_ASSOC);
print_r($sub);
```

There's a lot of subject in the book table with same user id, but it only retrieve first of it, why is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) returns array representation of **current row** only:

> Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

You have to use loop to iterate over all returned rows:

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT subject FROM book WHERE useid = $userid") or die(mysql_error());
while($sub = mysql_fetch_array($search, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($sub);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse result of this

```
while($sub = mysql_fetch_array($search, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
 print_r($sub);
}
```

Reason  for this

mysql_fetch_array function returns an associative array, but it also returns FALSE if there are no more rows to return! Using a PHP While Loop we can use this information to our advantage.

If we place the statement "$row = mysql_fetch_array()" as our while loop's conditional statement we will accomplish two things:

We will get a new row of MySQL information that we can print out each time the while loop checks its conditional statement.

When there are no more rows the function will return FALSE causing the while loop to stop!

Hence it will continue to print data until the function returns false

Answer (score 0):

As mysql* are officially  depreciated you should be using mysqli* or prepared statements

```
//$Conn =  new mysqli(host, username, pass, db);   
$sqlquery = "SELECT subject FROM book WHERE useid = $userid";    
//Execute the query reurns data into a $result
$result = $Conn->query($sqlquery);    
//results into a associative array
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
print_r($resultArray);
```

OR [**PDOStatement::fetchAll**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("your query");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: That's a good advise but it however  it doesn't answer the original question OP asked.

Comment: @AmalMurali I have provided the answer using pdo/mysqli then why i will provide OP the answer as mysql_fetch_array will work with loop other wise OP  will get first record so i assume my answer should relate to proper code that i have provided if i am using different technique to answer